# Use updateConnectionProperties to change to new data source which is not in dataset

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, data-source

I am using updateConnectionProperties() method to change data sources for layer files. The layer is "C:/gis/layer.lyrx". The old path is "C:/gis/oldGDB.gdb/oldDS/FC". The new path is "C:/gis/newGDB.gdb/FC". As you can see, the new data source is not in a feature dataset like the old one. First I tried:

```
lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile('C:/gis/layer.lyrx')
lyr.updateConnectionProperties('C:/gis/oldGDB.gdb', 'C:/gis/newGDB.gdb')
lyr.saveACopy('C:/gis/newLayer.lyrx')
```

When I check the property of newLayer.lyrx, its data source is unchanged - still the FC in oldDS in oldGDB.gdb. Then I tried:

```
lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile('C:/gis/layer.lyrx')
lyr.updateConnectionProperties('', 'C:/gis/newGDB.gdb')
lyr.saveACopy('C:/gis/newLayer.lyrx')
```

The data source did change this time, but it assumed that the new source is still in a dataset, and thus it could not find the new source. Lastly, I tried:

```
lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile('C:/gis/layer.lyrx')
lyr.updateConnectionProperties('', {'connection_info': 
   {'database': 'C:/gis/newGDB.gdb'}, 
    'dataset': '', 
    'workspace_factory': 'File Geodatabase'})
lyr.saveACopy('C:/gis/newLayer.lyrx')
```

Again, the data source did not change. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but maybe it will help people finding this post and having the same problem. The `.updateConnectionProperties` method did nothing when used on layer in my case, so a defined a function using the [Python CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) to change the data source from a featureclass file in a GDB.

In this function, no need to specify the feature dataset name, arcpy will handle this automatically (because you can't have feactureclass with the same name in a gdb). This work with GDB that don't have feature dataset AND with GDB that have feature class datasets.

```py
def update_layer_source(layer, new_gdb_path, new_feature_name, new_feature_dataset=None):
    """Use Python CIM access to modify a layer data source
    https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm
    """
    if not isinstance(layer, arcpy._mp.Layer):
        raise TypeError(f"layer arg must be a arcpy.mp.Layer object")
    lyrCIM = layer.getDefinition('V3') 
    data_source = lyrCIM.featureTable.dataConnection
    
    data_source.dataset = new_feature_name
    data_source.workspaceConnectionString = f'DATABASE={new_gdb_path}'
    if new_feature_dataset !=None: 
        data_source.featureDataset = new_feature_dataset
    
    layer.setDefinition(lyrCIM)
    
    return None
```

How to use :

```py
# Import your lyr file or select it in the map
_map = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT").listMaps('your_map_name')[0]
lyr = _map.listLayers('your_lyr_name')[0]

# Change Data Source of your layer
update_layer_source(lyr, 'your_new_gdb_path', 'your_new_feature_name')
```

Comment: Very nice workaround. However your function didn't work for me when I was changing feature class data source between different datasets in different gdbs (i.e. updating data source from a.gdb/a1/fc to b.gdb/b1/fc). To make it working in my case I modified function signature to *'def update_layer_source(layer, new_gdb_path, new_feature_name, new_feature_dataset=None:'*  and then in function body after defining data_source I've added *'if new_feature_dataset !=None: data_source.featureDataset = new_feature_dataset*'

Comment: thx, I added your suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile('C:/gis/layer.lyrx')
current_conn = lyr.connectionProperties
new_conn = {'dataset':'your_new_file', 
            'workspace_factory': 'File Geodatabase',
            'connection_info':{'database': 'your_gdb_path'})
lyr.updateConnectionProperties(current_conn, new_conn)
lyr.saveACopy('C:/gis/newLayer.lyrx')
```

Comment: It says 'LayerFile' object has no attribute 'connectionProperties'. I am having trouble understanding the difference between Layer class and LayerFile class. My layer file has only one layer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be tripping up on the forward slashes, see if this works:

```py
lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r'C:\gis\layer.lyrx')

for layer in lyr.listLayers():
    layer.updateConnectionProperties(r'C:\old.gdb', r'C:\data\newGDB.gdb')

lyr.saveACopy(r'C:\gis\newLayer.lyrx')
```

(I suspect `lyr.updateConnectionProperties(r'C:\old.gdb', r'C:\data\newGDB.gdb')` would do the trick, too).

A layer file can, theoretically, contain multiple layers at its top level so think of it as a container that has-many layers, not a layer itself.

Comment: I tried updateConnectionProperties on both the layer file and the layer with r'C:\...' but neither worked. The data source was not updated at all. The only way that I could actually update the data source was to use empty string as the first parameter in updateConnectionProperties(). I also tried layer.updateConnectionProperties(layer.connectionProperties, r'C:\gis\newGDB.gdb') in the for loop and it still didn't update anything.

Comment: It seems to me that updateConnectionProperties only works if: 1) both the old and the new data sources are not in datasets, or 2) both the old and the new data sources are in datasets with the same name.

Comment: As Boyang noted the issue is with datasets and not with forward slashes